# How to get all term meta for a taxonomy - getting term_meta for taxonomy

Tags: post-meta, terms, wpdb, meta-value

**TL;DR**: I'm trying to get the meta_value `display_type` for a taxonomy, but it returns blank (even though I can see it in the database).

---

This question wants to access a term meta that is on a the taxonomy: `product_cat`, which is a taxonomy made by WooCommerce.

I'm asking this here instead of StackOverflow, since it's more related to WordPress than to WooCommerce.

In my database, I can see that there are a couple of lines in the database for the term with the `$term->ID = 15`.

```
meta_id    |  term_id  |  meta_key       |  meta-value
---------------------------------------------------
1          |  15       |  display_type   |  subcategories
2          |  15       |  thumbnail_id   |  0
204        |  15       |  product_....   |  45
676        |  15       |  an_acf_field   |  test
676        |  15       |  _an_acf_field  |  field_123abc123abc
```

But for some reason then this returns empty:

```
$term = get_queried_object(); // in the file taxonomy-product-cat.php
$display_type = get_term_meta( $term->ID, 'display_type' ); // $term->ID = 15
echo '<pre>';
print_r($display_type);
echo '</pre>';
// Returns empty
```

So I figured that I could debug it, by getting all `term_meta` for that ID (15). But I can't find any WordPress-function that get's all the meta_fields?

---

### Solution attempts

**Attempt 1 - Using WPDB**

I could do something like this:

```
global $wpdb;
$test = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_termmeta WHERE term_id = '15'");
```

But it just seems like a non-WordPress-kinda-way.

---

**Attempt 2 - `get_term_meta` without key**

A wild guess was to just do this:

```
$term = get_queried_object(); 
$display_type = get_term_meta( $term->ID ); // !! No key defined
echo '<pre>';
print_r($display_type);
echo '</pre>';
// Still returns empty
```

---

**Attempt 3 - Looking into WooCommerce documentation**

I can see that WooCommerce access the `display_type` itself [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/23710744c01ded649d6a94a4eaea8745e543159f/includes/rest-api/Controllers/Version1/class-wc-rest-product-categories-v1-controller.php#L55)

like this:

```
$display_type = get_term_meta( $item->term_id, 'display_type', true );
```

... So it baffles me that it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using `$term->ID`. Taxonomy terms do not have an `ID` property. They have a `term_id` property:

```
$display_type = get_term_meta( $term->term_id );
```

You'll notice that WooCommerce is using this, while your attempts are not.